# display error message block only when form has error by css only

Tags: html, css

can I display error div only when form has error?  I know how to implement by javascript, but, if possible, I want to do this in css only.

I tried write css like following, but it does not work.
input tag anywhere in html. not only case next sibling of error div.

Error div shows only form has :invalid some where in html.

```html
<div id="message">
  error.
</div>

<input class="required" required>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="required" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
#message {
  display: none;
}

#message:has(:root .required:invalid) {
  display: block;
}

.required:invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

You can try this sample by codepen.
https://codepen.io/sforest1975/pen/poxMbYJ

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

> This pseudo-class presents a way of selecting a parent element or a previous sibling element with respect to a reference element by taking a relative selector list as an argument.

Your `#message` is not a *parent* of anything that might be invalid here. And for it to be selected based on any following *siblings*, you need to use a combinator in your relative selector first.

`#message:has(~ .required:invalid)` would select it based on any following invalid input *sibling*.

And to target it based on any inputs that are *nested into* following siblings, you need to allow for (at least) one element "in between" the two, so `#message:has(~ * .required:invalid)`

So to make it work for both of those scenarios, you need

```
#message:has(~ .required:invalid),
#message:has(~ * .required:invalid) {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility :

```css
:root:has(.required:invalid) #message{
  display: block;
}
```